# Pass custom error message AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On my index.php page, I have a form. When you submit the form, it goes to process.php, which runs the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login_button').click(function()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
        'email'         : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password'      : $('input[name=password]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'ajax/proclogin.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json',
        success     : function(data)
        {
            if (data.success == false)
            {
                if(data.errors.email)
                {
                    toastr.error('Email is blank. Type in an email.');
                }
                else if(data.errors.password)
                {
                    toastr.error('Password input is blank. Type in a password.');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                toastr.success('Works!', 'WooHoo!');
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

This then executes the following code which is the proclogin.php page:

```
<?php
// proc(ess)login.php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

if (empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors['email'] = 'Email field is blank.';
}

if (empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $errors['password'] = 'Password field is blank.';
}

// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if(empty($errors))
{

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message
        $connection = mysqli_connect("****","*****","*****","*****");
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']); # Define email field
        $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']); # Define password field

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM users WHERE Email='$email' LIMIT 1"); # Query what we need
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); # Fetch what we need

        $p = $row['Password']; # Define fetched details
        $email = $row['Email']; # Define fetched details
        if(password_verify($input, $p)) # Verify input password matches hashed password in the DB.
        {
            #It matches, let's set a session and redirect them to the dashboard.php page.
            //$_SESSION['SID'] = $email;
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'Success';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['message']  = 'failed';

       }
}
else 
{
    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

When the email field is blank, you get the error message that is written in the process.js page.
When the password field is blank, you get the error message that is written in the process.js page.

Neither of the error messages get pushed through from the proclogin.php. I'm not too fussed about that, what's bothering me is that the 'failed' one gets get pushed through to notify them of their credentials being wrong. I've played around with the code and tried to match what was above but I cannot get it to work.

I also created a $errors['deny'] = "Incorrect details"; and tried to push it through on the process.js page as data.errors.deny - is this the correct way? (new to AJAX/jQuery).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `data.message` in the case that the credentials are invalid?

Comment: I commented out the toastr and added alert(data.message) and get undefined. But if I type in incorrect details, i still don't get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass event in the function parameter. try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login_button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
        'email'         : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password'      : $('input[name=password]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'proclogin.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json',
        success     : function(data)
        {
            if (data.success == false)
            {
                if(data.errors.email)
                {
                    toastr.error(data.errors.email);
                }
                else if(data.errors.password)
                {
                    toastr.error(data.errors.password);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                toastr.success('Works!', 'WooHoo!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

Using the latest toastr and jquery, this works fine

in proclogin.php you need to modify this part of the code:

```
if(password_verify($input, $p)) # Verify input password matches hashed password in the DB.
        {
            #It matches, let's set a session and redirect them to the dashboard.php page.
            //$_SESSION['SID'] = $email;
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'Success';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['errors']['password']  = 'Pass not match';

       }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Correct details work and I get the "works" alert. I don't get the error message to say details are incorrect.

Comment: What's the error. Did you check your browser console?

Comment: It says "data.errors" is undefined(with Firefox)
With chrome I get:
process.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: OK, got it, in your proclogin.php, password verified failed, so it expected data.errors in the ajax message. but you did not defined that.

Comment: Can you help? I know nothing about AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the update - worked a treat.

In future then, if I was to add another field, for example, 2FA field and wanted to do the same error message, would i do a $data['errors']['2FA'] = Error and then on process.js I put if(data.errors.2fa)..?

Comment: 2fa would not be suitable name. fa2 would be better

Comment: If my answer helps, you can click the accepted tick icon.